# How to extract text from html in Python with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, rest, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract its text i.e only the filename from the below html tags

So in the end I would like to have output as below-

```
BeforeStructure.PNG
AfterStructure.PNG
```

Can you please guide how to I extract only the file name from the below code, Thanks!

```
<div><br> </div><div><img src=\"https://azure.com/8dd91aab-0dce-41e2-95d4-eb69e06c68fe/_apis/wit/attachments/c4e5aab1-0877-44ea-ad2d-2c614ac56984?fileName=BeforeStructure.PNG\" alt=BeforeStructure.PNG><br> </div><div><br> </div><div><img src=\"https://azure.com/8dd91aab-0dce-41e2-95d4-eb69e06c68fe/_apis/wit/attachments/af842f67-1a3d-48dc-8c8b-396a28b306ce?fileName=AfterStructure.PNG\" alt=AfterStructure.PNG><br> </div>"
```

Comment: please show what you tried

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to extract the file name from the link in the `src` attribute, you can just extract the name in the `alt` attribute.

```
for img in soup.find_all("img"):
  print(img.get("alt"))
```

Output -

```
BeforeStructure.PNG
AfterStructure.PNG
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File_name = soup.find(‘file name’).getText()
```

This works for 1 find, if you want to find in multiple locations then use find all